# How to checkout older version using TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

How do I checkout a file or folder to a specific revision in my working copy? I only want to view the files, not edit or check them in.

I would prefer to do this with the TortoiseSVN client.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

right-click on the folder, in the TSVN submenu select `update to revision...`, then enter the revision or date and click the OK button.